# Burn the [bullet] tag (and re-tag to [bulletphysics])

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There are [bullet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bullet) (215 questions) and [bulletphysics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bulletphysics) (311 questions) that serve the exact same purpose. Both refer to the [Bullet Physics Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_(software)).

The first links to https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3. (newer)
The second links to http://code.google.com/p/bullet/. (which is an old archive)

I presume [bullet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bullet) should be burninated, and simply re-tag such questions as [bulletphysics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bulletphysics).
However, [bulletphysics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bulletphysics) should be updated to use the newer link.

Comment: I totally agree on that.

Comment: I think synonymisation would be the better option here.

Comment: What about `<ul><li>actual bullets?</li></ul>`?

Comment: @user234461 Tag wiki for [tag:bullet] includes: "_Do not use this for bullet points. Use [tag:bulletedlist] instead. For bulleted lists in HTML, use [tag:html-lists]._" The former has 110 questions. The latter 5,131 as of this time of posting.

Comment: @user234461that would be a hardware question and therefore belong in [su]... oh wait, wrong sort of bullets.

Comment: @Haem For even more clarification, some of bullet-ammo-related questions should be tagged as `pewpew` instead of `projectile`.   It would be my next meta question.

Comment: Wait... Bullet physics are on topic on StackOverflow?

Comment: Can you fix the `achieve` to `archive` if that is what you mean?

Comment: @smileycreations15 I fixed the misspelling, thank.

Answer (score 13):

[bullet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bullet) should be burned rather than synonymized. In practice, it's used for a variety of meanings:

- Video game bullets: [JAVA Efficient way to draw bullets firing from character to mouse position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55487140/java-efficient-way-to-draw-bullets-firing-from-character-to-mouse-position), [Pygame- bullet and enemy collision without Sprite or classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278813/pygame-bullet-and-enemy-collision-without-sprite-or-classes)
- Bulleted lists: [bullet lists not rendering in blogdown .rmd file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55186599/bullet-lists-not-rendering-in-blogdown-rmd-file), [How to remove bullets from Unordered list nested in Div's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154198/how-to-remove-bullets-from-unordered-list-nested-in-divs)
- And Bullet Physics SDK, it's intended meaning.

It's worth noting that the tag excerpt even explicitly warns against these other usages, but they persist in significant percentages anyway. This indicates that [bullet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bullet) is too unclear to serve as a tag. Therefore, it should not remain available, even as a synonym.

Comment: Thank .... I agree ... so what is the next step of the procedure?  I mean  ... the tag will not disappear just because I asked it here, right?  Should I do anything - or just accept your great answer?

Comment: @javaLover I would edit the question to remove the parts about creating synonyms. After that, you wait until the community begins the burn. (Yes, the burn process is horribly inefficient. SO, the company, seems to have no interest in improving it or changing it at all.)